# Are stored procedures the only way to reliably set a datetime field with the server's modification time?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, mapping

Here are the requirements:

- We have a table with a `lastModifiedOn` column.
- We want that column to really, reliably, reflect the (utc) time at which the field was last updated in the database.
- We want that to still be the case when modifying the contents of the tables with Entity Framework.

Right now, we are doing that with a `ModificationFunctionMapping/UpdateFunction` element in the MSL and a stored procedure defined in the SSDL file.

Is there another way of achieving the same effect, without having to use a Stored Procedure?

EDIT:
In the end, I was not clear enough.

When I said that the "stored procedure [was] defined in the SSDL file", I meant to say that the stored procedure's name was defined in the SSDL file - but the problem was that I had to deploy stored procedures with these names on the database, which could conceivably create problems in the event of multiple EF models.
Now that I have understood the use of the `<CommandText>` element in the SSDL `<Function>` element, I have been able to put the custom SQL along with the rest of the Entity Framework model - which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `lastModifiedOn` column with a trigger inserting `current_timestamp`. I'm presuming the database server is a Sql Server.

Comment: While I like that solution - particularly because it places the burden of that concern where it belongs - it is sadly not an option for us (in fact, part of the problem is that the system has grown complex enough that the implementation of these triggers is inconsistent and cannot be relied on.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Filip, in our application we also have a Column for LastModifiedOn and we have created a trigger on the tables which updates this column with Current timestamp whenever row is updated in the table.

The Thing is you would require to create two triggers on the table, 
1.  Update Trigger : that would update LastModifiedOn Column with current timestamp whenever a row is updated.
2. Insert Trigger : that would insert current timestamp in LastModifiedOn Column whenever a row is created in the table.

Comment: cf. the comment on Filip's answer.

Comment: could you explain a bit more why the implementation of these triggers would be inconsistent?

Comment: Because there were no triggers on the tables at the beginning; now there are hundreds of databases on at least dozens of servers around the world, with a thousand of tables, linked in a rather complex replication system (7 databases are necessary in the simplest replication schema). In the end, on some tables, we have the triggers, and on other tables we don't; there is no way to know that in advance because it can depend on which of the hundreds of databases you are working on.

Comment: hmm.. that is one of its kind database. See, I would still go for triggers, initially it would be pain , but once triggers are created then it would be more consistent way of entering lastmodifiedtime. To automate things you can create a script that would created triggers on tables, if trigger exists then drop the trigger and again create the trigger. else your current approach is good.

Comment: The problem is with the "initially it would be pain" - "pain" in this case could mean that some of our sites stop functioning correctly for an unknown amount of time; a responsibility which is not mine to take (the one that could take that responsibility is the local IT department, for the site to which the database is attached.)

Comment: hmmm.. in that case I am out of answer, I hope someone else can provide you a better and easy solution. :)

Comment: @Sumit: Don't worry - my problem was having to deploy stored procedures to the database server. Now that I can confine that custom SQL to the SSDL file, the problem I wanted to solve is solved. (And I absolutely agree that, had triggers been reliably in place, that SQL would not even be necessary.)